# Calculating the total in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to automatically add a `SUM` formula to `grandtotal` for the new orders?

[image]

Comment: whats determines a new orders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with [tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) you can automatically add a formula in a column whenever new row is added to the table.

You can use below formula and it'll automatically add total for the last row of each order:
`=IF([@order]=A3,"",SUMIF([order],[@order],[total]))`

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!!!